# Get a JSON response for the API request

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get a json response for an API request.

```
$GEOCODE = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=$API_KEY&ip=70.27.250.191";

$json = file_get_contents($GEOCODE);
$data = json_decode($json);
dd($data);
```

returns the output: `null`. 
But when I tried it directly in the addrress bar, it's working. Am I doing it wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: What is the output of `dd($GEOCODE)`? It might work in the browser but is the `$API_KEY` being populated in the string?

Comment: `var_dump($json);` what do you get?

Comment: @DavidBarker: `string 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=shows-my-api-key-here&ip=70.27.250.191' (length=121)`

Comment: @Steve: thanks, it shows the output. :) Silly me

Comment: It returns: `string 'OK;;70.27.250.191;CA;Canada;Quebec;Montreal;H1A 0A1;45.5088;-73.5878;-05:00' (length=75)`

How can I get the latitude from this response?

Comment: It's not json. Maybe you need to tell the WS to return json. Or just `explode()` what you get.

Comment: @Marek: Yes, `&format=json` at the end helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request json:

```
$GEOCODE = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=$API_KEY&ip=70.27.250.191&format=json"; //<--THIS

$json = file_get_contents($GEOCODE);
$data = json_decode($json);
dd($data);

//output:

object(stdClass)#7 (11) {
  ["statusCode"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["statusMessage"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ipAddress"]=>
  string(13) "70.27.250.191"
  ["countryCode"]=>
  string(2) "CA"
  ["countryName"]=>
  string(6) "Canada"
  ["regionName"]=>
  string(6) "Quebec"
  ["cityName"]=>
  string(8) "Montreal"
  ["zipCode"]=>
  string(7) "H1A 0A1"
  ["latitude"]=>
  string(7) "45.5088"
  ["longitude"]=>
  string(8) "-73.5878"
  ["timeZone"]=>
  string(6) "-05:00"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a valid format you want to receive your response in. According to [IP Info DB's official documentation](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php), API returns raw response. In order to get a JSON response, include parameter `format` in your API request. So your API URL now becomes:

`$GEOCODE = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=$API_KEY&format=json&ip=70.27.250.191";`